# Factorise $x^{15}+1$ into two integer polynomials, one of degree 6 and one of degree 9

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, factoring

This question was asked as one of the electrical engineering entrance problems in my country, where the term *integer polynomial* means precisely a polynomial with integer coefficients. The answer given is:
$$\left(x^9+2x^8+x^7-x^6-2x^5-2x^4-x^3+x^2+2x+1\right)\\ \times \left( x^6-2x^5+3x^4-3x^3+3x^2-2x+1\right)$$

---

**My attempt:**

My first instinct upon seeing the problem was to consider the factorisation of $x^5+1$ into polynomials of degree two and three, hoping that the degree six and nine polynomials in the question can be recovered by letting $x \mapsto x^3$. Then it occurred to me that I could not do this to get factorisations with nice (integer) coefficients.

One representation I derived was the not-so-good-looking
$$ x^5+1 = \left[ x^3 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)x^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)x + 1 \right]\left[ x^2 - \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)x +1 \right] $$
Which isn't an integer polynomial.

Then I tried to reverse engineer a solution from the answer key provided, to no avail. I noticed that both polynomials in the factorisation are *symmetric*, in the sense that the coefficients are palindromic: $(1, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1)$ and $(1, -2, 3, -3, 3, -2, 1)$, although I am not sure how this might help solve the problem.

Comment: It helps if you know the cyclomatic polynomials. $x^{15}+1$ has as roots the $30$th roots of $1$ which are of even order. So the polynomials factors as $\Phi_2(x)\Phi_6(x)\Phi_{10}(x)\Phi_{30}(x),$ where $\Phi_n$ are the cyclomatic polynomials, of degree $\phi(n),$ which is $1,2,4,8$ for $n=2,6,10,30.$ So the factorization is $\Phi_2(x)\Phi_{30}(xj$ of degree $9$ and $\Phi_6(x)\Phi_{10}(x)$ of degree $6.

Comment: Because of $x^{30}-1=(x^{15}-1)(x^{15 }+1)$ we can use the known factorization of  $x^{30}-1$ to obtain $$x^{15}+1=(x^8 + x^7 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1)(x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1)(x^2 - x + 1)(x + 1)$$ as Thomas said. Now multiply the degree $8$ one with $(x+1)$ and the other two to obtain a degree $6$ polynomial.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - "cyclotomic", not "cyclomatic"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I haven't heard of them before, but I'll note them down for when I have the necessary knowledge.

Comment: Ah, I often switch the two. One is a math word related to roots of unity, the other is a computer code complexity metric. @mr_e_man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the formula
$$x^n+1=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(x-e^{\frac{\left(2k+1\right)\pi i}{n}}\right)$$
You can split you polynomial into $4$ polynomials of degree $1, 2,4$ and $8$:
$$\underbrace{(x + 1)}_{k=7} \underbrace{(x^2 - x + 1)}_{k=2,12} \underbrace{(x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1)}_{k=1,4,10,13} \underbrace{(x^8 + x^7 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1)}_{k=3,5,6,8,9,11,14,15}$$

the different $k$'s are grouped in such a way that simplifying $\dfrac{2k+1}{15}$, these have the same denominator:

*Example*
$a_k=\dfrac{2k+1}{15}$ for $k=1,4,10,13\Rightarrow a_k=\dfrac{1}{5},\dfrac{3}{5},\dfrac{7}{5},\dfrac{9}{5}$

So if you want a polynomial of degrees $6$ and $9$

$$p_6(x)=(x^2 - x + 1) (x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1)$$
$$p_9(x)=(x+1)(x^8 + x^7 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1)$$

So

$$p_6(x)=x^6 - 2 x^5 + 3 x^4 - 3 x^3 + 3 x^2 - 2 x + 1$$
$$p_9(x)=x^9 + 2 x^8 + x^7 - x^6 - 2 x^5 - 2 x^4 - x^3 + x^2 + 2 x + 1$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. I organised the different k's as described and trivially worked out the polynomials of degree 1, 2, and 4, and then carried out synthetic division on $x^15+1$ to get the remaining polynomial of degree 8. Is there a quicker way to compute the polynomial of degree 8?

Comment: @jphys Using the sum of cubes identity $\,x^{15}+1=(x^5+1)(x^{10}-x^5+1)\,$. The first factor further factors into the linear and quartic factors, while the second factor is a [palindromic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) which you can factor with the standard substitution $\,z = x + \frac{1}{x}\,$.

Answer (score 2):

(This is equivalent to Fabio Caiazzo's answer, but I'm writing it in more low-brow terms for people who aren't familiar with roots of unity and cyclotomic polynomials.)

Notice that $x^{15}+1$ is divisible by both $x^5+1$ and $x^3+1$, by writing $x^{15}$ as either $(x^5)^3$ or $(x^3)^5$ and using the formula for the sum of odd powers.  Each of these two factors is itself divisible by $x+1$, but after factoring that out, they are relatively prime.  So you can take the degree-$6$ factor to be
$$
\frac{x^5+1}{x+1} \cdot \frac{x^3+1}{x+1},
$$
from which you can find the degree-$9$ factor by long division.